# Delete rows based on timestamp AND text in a separate column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to modify the script provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50810024) that deletes rows with a timestamp older than 30 days to work with my Google Sheet. I would like the function to additionally only delete rows where column 4 ("D") contains the word "Books" only. Other rows, ideally those where column 4 contains "Books" with other words ("Books, Shirts" and the like) should stay regardless of date.

I tried adding an additional var containing that column but it's still deleting regardless. Maybe because I'm not familiar with how an array handles text.

My code so far:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Requests");//applies to active requests sheet only
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array
  
var currentDate = new Date();//today
var monthOld = Date.now() + -30*24*3600*1000; 
for (i=lastrow;i>=1;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][0];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col1 = [0]
if ((tempDate!="") && (tempDate <= (monthOld)))
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very straightforward to do that.

Just get the values of column D and add an additional condition in the if statement:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Active Requests");//applies to active requests sheet only
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array
  
var currentDate = new Date();//today
var monthOld = Date.now() + -30*24*3600*1000; 
for (i=lastrow;i>=1;i--) {
var tempDate = values[i-1][0];// arrays are 0 indexed so row1 = values[0] and col1 = [0]
var bookCheck = values[i-1][3];// values in column D
if ( (tempDate!="") && (tempDate <= (monthOld)) && bookCheck=="Books")
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}
}
```